# VB6 Subscript Out fo Range - but this is an odd one because a mirror function is working fine

Tags: vb6

Thanks for reading.

I have built a VB6 DLL (VB_InterFace  just for a name) that talks to a C# DLL (C#_Driver just for a name) that talks to a Bluetooth Device.

The Demo VB6 test app (VB_Demo just for a name) I created as stage one works fine, does what it is supposed to. It calls the VB_Interface and Opens and Closes the BTDevice. Additional functions also work fine.

However on placing the operational code from VB_Interface into another DLL that is the live operations DLL, Open works fine, but Close is throwing an error. "Variable not defined" when returning from the C#_Driver.

I just can't see why, the code is the same, the process is only marginally different. By this I mean ;

In the VB_Demo I have two buttons "Open" "Close" and when I click on these I get the feedback that I expect from the BTDevice.

```
Private Sub btnOpenPort_Click()

'MsgBox steps(0)
    ReDim steps(5)

    Dim rc As HF4000_ResultCodes
    'rc = driver.OpenSerial(cmbPorts.Text)

    If driver.OpenSerial(cmbPorts.Text) = True Then


Private Sub btnClosePort_Click()

    Dim rc As HF4000_ResultCodes

    If driver.CloseSerial("COM4") = True Then
```

However in the live DLL it just executes the same functions internally without being initiated by a button click.

```
' See IScanDevice documentation.
' @see IScanDevice#OpenDevice
Private Function IScanDevice_OpenDevice() As Scanning.Scan_ResultCodes
          (truncated slightly)
50      If driver.OpenSerial("COM4") = True Then
            rc = READY
            MsgBox "Connected to the device successfully."


' See IScanDevice documentation.
' @see IScanDevice#CloseDevice
Private Function IScanDevice_CloseDevice() As Scanning.Scan_ResultCodes
            (truncated slightly)
50        If driver.CloseSerial("COM4") = True Then
60          rc = READY
70          IScanDevice_CloseDevice = Scan_Success
```

clsDriver.cls

```
Public Event OnStateChanged(newState As String)

Public Event OnDataUpdated()

Dim WithEvents CSharpInteropServiceEvents As CSharpInteropService.LibraryInvoke
Dim load As New LibraryInvoke


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
  Set CSharpInteropServiceEvents = load
End Sub

Private Sub CSharpInteropServiceEvents_MessageEvent(ByVal newState As String)

   If newState = "OpenForm1" Then
   '   FormDummy2.Show  ' Not required
   End If

  If State <> newState Then
    State = newState
    RaiseEvent OnStateChanged(State)
    GetDriverData
  End If

End Sub

Private Function BluetoothTestInvoke(load, functionName, param)
    BluetoothTestInvoke = load.GenericInvoke("BluetoothTest.dll", "BluetoothTest.Class1", functionName, param)
End Function

Function OpenSerial(portNumber)   '   "COM4"
  Dim param(0) As Variant
  Dim retorno As Variant

  param(0) = portNumber
  retorno = BluetoothTestInvoke(load, "OpenSerial", param)

  OpenSerial = retorno(0)    <<<<<<<  Works fine returns TRUE

End Function

Function CloseSerial(portNumber)   '   "COM4"
  Dim param(0) As Variant
  Dim retorno As Variant

  param(0) = portNumber
  retorno = BluetoothTestInvoke(load, "CloseSerial", param)

  CloseSerial = retorno(0)    <<<<<<<<< "Error Subscript Out of Range"

End Function
```

What I have discovered is this - and I guess this is the reason why the Close is not working. The question is why is this situation occurring ...

When driver.OpenSerial executes, it hits > Function OpenSerial
Within Function OpenSerial it executes BluetoothTestInvoke where "load" is "CSharpInteropService.LibraryInvoke"
From there it moves to - Sub CSharpInteropServiceEvents_MessageEvent

.. and everything is fine.

However when I then execute driver.CloseSerial  after that, it hits > Function CloseSerial
Within Function OpenSerial it executes BluetoothTestInvoke where "load" is "CSharpInteropService.LibraryInvoke"

Now here it "should" move to - Sub CSharpInteropServiceEvents_MessageEvent

However No, it just drops to the next line which is  CloseSerial = retorno(0)

and this is where I get the "Subscript out of range"  error for   retorno(0)

For some reason in the CloseSerial it is not invoking "load" 
BluetoothTestInvoke(load, "CloseSerial", param)

Thoughts and suggestions much appreciated.

UPDATE

Quite right, one should never assume anything.

On the tips I started digging deeper into the C# Library. It turns out the "param"  value that is the Bluetooth port is passed into the CloseSerial call, and from there is is passed around within the external C# library dll. At one stage it is reset so the port number that should be handled is lost, thus it doesn't close but specifically the "expected" data was not returned to the calling app.

```
  param(0) = portNumber
  retorno = BluetoothTestInvoke(load, "CloseSerial", param)   <<  param was being reset in the external library.
```

Comment: One suggestion would be a little defensive programming.  You are assuming `retorno` contains an array.  Don't make this assumption.  Make sure element 0 exists before you access it.  This doesn't address why it's not working, but at least it won't crash if you do this.

Comment: Somewhat random guess, but have you done a clean rebuild and made sure no old COM DLLs remain registered in the wrong places? Just to ensure that all the code you think is being executed really is so?

Comment: Actually, are you able to run both the C# and VB6 code in their respective debuggers & step trace through it as it executes? That should be possible and might make some unknown factor more visible.

Comment: @UuDdLrLrSs Thanks for the ideas all, yes tried that also, no go.

Comment: Just getting back on the outcome of this. With the tip from @Brian M Stafford, I started digging deeper into the C# library and found the bug. I have mentioned it in the Update above.